# click jquery on a video doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

When I try to click on video using js in Friefox click and display in console the id of the video it doesn't work. Why?

```js
$('.videoclass').click(function() {
  console.log(this);
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  console.log(id);
})
```

```html
<video controls="" id="ui-id-1" class="videoclass" style="position: absolute; top: 118px; left: 61px;" width="320" height="240">    <source id="videoavantuuid" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
```

Comment: No, and firefox detected the script.

Comment: It is working please see https://jsfiddle.net/tkbv7sfo/

Comment: Yes @Priya but only on chrome. I try with firefox 61 and it doesn't work

Comment: Please add whole html file code, so I can see if it is related to jQuery file loading

Comment: I can't show all the source code. I think is very very bizarre. @Priya

Comment: I have a idea : I will try click with pure js.

Answer (score 3):

## Firefox controls is the Whole Video Tag

---

### Problem

> *"When I try to click on video using js in <del>Friefox</del> Firefox click and display in console the id of the video it doesn't work. Why? "*

---

### Explanation

Firefox has a play button center poster and Chrome does not. This is an obvious indicator that FF has `controls` attribute that covers the entire tag and Chrome does not, it's `controls` are accessible only at the bottom where the bar is.

Firefox video tag is interpreting the click on it's `controls` property first so the click event registered on `.vid` is never fired or more likely event was fired then `e.stopPropagation()` was called so nothing else would be triggered by a click.

---

### Recap

To summarize so far:

1. Firefox video tag behavior: responds to click events with play/pause but no other callbacks are triggered.
2. Firefox `controls` interacts with all click events directed to the video tag.

---

## Solution ⭐

If you need `controls` on the video tag, then do not register the click event on the video tag. Register an alternate yet similar event instead:

`mousedown`,`focus`, `contextmenu`, etc.

---

### Demo

Review the Demo with Firefox:

- There's 3 video tags:

**#ID**      **[controls]**      **Event**             **Result on Firefox v.60.0.2**

**`#vid0`** ---- **`true`** ------ **`click`** --------- Plays video / Does not run callback

**`#vid1`** --- **`false`** ------ **`click`** --------- Does not play video / Runs callback

**`#vid2`** ---- **`true`** ------ **`focus`** --------- Plays video / Runs callback ⭐

```js
$('.vid').on("click", identify);

$('.ff').on('focus', identify); //⭐

function identify(e) {
  var eventcurrentTarget = e.currentTarget.id;
  var eventTarget = e.target.id;
  var thisId = this.id;
  console.log({
    eventcurrentTarget,
    eventTarget,
    thisId
  });
}
```

```css
figure {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px 0
}

figcaption {
  font-size: 32px
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  margin-left: 325px;
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 96%
}

.as-console-row:after {
  display: none !important
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>#vid0</figcaption>
  <video id="vid0" class="vid" width="320" height="240" controls>   
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
</figure>

<figure>
  <figcaption>#vid1</figcaption>
  <video id="vid1" class="vid" width="320" height="240">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
</figure>

<figure>
  <figcaption>#vid2 ⭐</figcaption>
  <video id="vid2" class="ff" width="320" height="240" controls>   
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
</figure>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the below piece of the code

```
$('.videoclass').click(function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.videoclass', function(){
```

and it should work.

Comment: They're functionally equivalent and did you even test your code because it still doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I try this is the same result @j08691

Comment: Mhhh, yes and no, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Comment: No, there's no yes and no here. You're suggestion is only useful for dynamically added elements and there's no indication at all that this is what the OP is doing.